# Folder permissions are Read-Only causing ProcessExplorer not to execute under Win8.1 x64

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, file-permissions

OMG!  I'm going nuts.  Yes, I've read the articles regarding that the RO flag on a dir means to look at customizations in desktop.ini, but seems like Process Explorer didn't get the memo.

I DLed the latest, copy the files to a directory and try and execute it and it gives me this dialogue:

[image: Process Explorer Error Message]

I had thought it was the permissions but now that I've read several of the articles on here, I guess it is not the case.  The previous version that I had did work, but when I tried to recopy it, it fails too with the same error.

The following have probably changed since it worked last:

1. I moved parts of my Home directory from C to D using the Properties->Location option, but I can't see that as a problem.  There are junctions from my actual home folder to the place I moved them to for my own convenience, but that shouldn't cause any issues either.
2. My computer is running Symantec Endpoint Protection, which I tried to add procexp.exe as an exception in it's options, but to no avail.  Disabling it isn't possible due to corporate policy.

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Hmmm....have you tried working with your companys'  system administration staff?

Comment: @mdpc, its late and they aren't here.

Comment: is the temp folder accessible?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: That is assuming that it is corporate IT related.  Still haven't confirmed that.

Comment: It's very strange.  I have to run it under Administrator privileges to get it to run.  That never happened before.  Not sure what changed.  As a workaround, I've copied the `procexp64.exe` file that was generated in the temp directory and put it in the directory next to my `procexp.exe` and running it directly from that.  Still would like to know what is causing this issue.